# How to properly manage what has been read from a .txt

Tags: java, split

I've been currently assigned to read from a `.txt`, and make a structure with what I've read. This is an example of what I should read:

```
Name1$Surname1$Programming&5.0#Mathematics&6.5#Algebra&7.2#History&6.7#Biology&6.9
```

I have no problems whatsoever when it comes to read the first two strings, however, from that point on i don't know how to manage, in order to properly split it and make new objects with them.

Any tips/ suggestions on how to do it pls?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what language you are using to read from .txt. Also please paste code on what you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.code/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You just need to find the pattern. You have a name and surname. After that you have a list of courses, each having a grade value. You should have a look at the `split()` and `join()` functions in Java. You can concatenate these functions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Weird structure.

1. Split at '$'
2. First element of that split is the Name, second the Surname.
3. Split the third element at '#'.
4. Split each element of the result of step 3 again at '&' to get course and grade.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) how to split strings.